# Detect and handle slow internet connection in React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

Currently I am using ***NetInfo*** of react-native and with the help of EffectiveConnectionType, I am able to find the connection is in :
***2g, 3g, 4g and unknown***. But is there any optimise way to handle this problem ?

Comment: Maybe do some small api calls to a few servers and test how long this takes?

Comment: it takes 20 seconds if connectivity is slow and I have added timeout  of 10 sec also but my scenario here is what if connection goes and comes i mean not stable and at this point the child component should re-render.

Comment: react-native-offline is a useful library. It allows you to configure what a slow connection is to you by allowing you to set a custom timeout to a ping server (google by default). You can also set an interval to check the connection status every x amount of time

Comment: @dentemm agree but is there any other alternative solution for the same I mean without using any library.

Comment: Unfortunately not as far as I know, I also migrated from NetInfo to the RN-offline library because of the NetInfo limitations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/rgommezz/react-native-offline ***or***
you can simply add ***timeout in axios***...if request is aborted after particular time say 10 sec...re-hit the same API request and set the count limit if count limit exceeds...You can show the slow internet message.

Answer (score 2):

I use the react-native-offline lib.

Among other things, `withNetworkConnectivity()` that frequently ping an url, `offline queues` to never miss an action...

https://github.com/rgommezz/react-native-offline